# Failed to parse netParameter file

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

```
>py yolo.py --video-path='F:/Data_Science/Python37/Scripts/YOLO/videos/lowres.mp4'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yolo.py", line 88, in <module>
    net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(FLAGS.config, FLAGS.weights)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_importer.cpp:214: error:  
 (-212:Parsing error) Failed to parse NetParameter file: ./yolov3- 
 coco/yolov3.weights in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20181221::readNetFromDarknet'
```

why am I getting a parse error? Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Add the absolute path of the cgf and weight files while adding them

example :
modelConfiguration = "D:/yoloObj/res/yolov2-tiny.cfg"
modelWeights = "D:/yoloObj/res/yolov3-tiny.weights"

Answer (score 2):

```
! wget "https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights"
```

Run this command and save the `yolo.weight` file in `yolov3-coco`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and the problem was in file paths. Absolute file paths solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may have using opencv 4 version.Try installing opencv-3.4.2.*

> pip install opencv-python==3.4.2.16

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have tried this and it works for me. Just Give the path where the yolov3.weights, coco.names etc in your darknet folder. Like, right-click where you stored the file and copy the path.
Like drive/darkflow/coco.names

Answer (score 0):

Download the file 'yolov3.weights' from the link and save it into your working directory:
https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30564906)