# using caffe model to detect face but gets this error:Failed to parse NetParameter file: F:/deep-learnin g/ESPCN01/deploy.prototxt

Tags: python, opencv, caffe, face-detection

I'm using a pretrained caffe model to do the face-detection of a picture, and the detection code is downloaded online. when just executing the first line of code, two errors came up.
I've made couples of attempts from the similar questions' answers.
i.e. change the relative file paths to absolute ones->not work,
change single quotes to double quotes->not work
I'm pretty sure that I have installed two files into my dir, is it because I did not config the caffe environment or something else? Someone could help me? Thanks in advance.

```
[libprotobuf ERROR C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\text_format.c
c:288] Error parsing text-format opencv_caffe.NetParameter: 1788:9: Message type "opencv_caffe.DetectionOutputParameter" has n
o field named "clip".
File "MainWindow.py", line 229, in face_detect_dnn
    net=cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("F:/deep-learning/ESPCN01/deploy.prototxt","F:/deep-learning/ESPCN01/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_1
40000_fp16.caffemodel")

cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1147: erro
r: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse NetParameter file: F:/deep-learnin
g/ESPCN01/deploy.prototxt in function 'cv::dnn::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie'
```

and the code below, just executed first line!

```
def face_detect_dnn(img_name, img_label):
    net=cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("F:/deep-learning/ESPCN01/deploy.prototxt","F:/deep-learning/ESPCN01/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel")
#     img = cv2.imread(path+img_name) # read picture
#     height, width, channel = image.shape  # 
#     # face detection
#     blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))  # 
#     net.setInput(blob)  # 
#     detections = net.forward()  # detection result
#     faces = detections[0, 0]  # face result
#     for face in faces:
#         confidence = face[2]  # 
#         if confidence > 0.5:  # thresh
#             box = face[3:7] * np.array([width, height, width, height])  # the coordinates
#             pt1 = int(box[0]), int(box[1])  # 
#             pt2 = int(box[2]), int(box[3])  # 
#             cv2.rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)  # draw rectangle

#             text = '{:.2f}%'.format(confidence * 100)  # show confidence
#             startX, startY = pt1
#             y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
#             org = (startX, y)  # 文本的左下角坐标
#             cv2.putText(image, text, org, cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)  # draw confidence
#     cv2.imwrite(path+'detect_'+img_name, img)# 保存图片
#     img_file = Image.open(path+'detect_'+img_name)
#     photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_file)
#     img_label.config(imag=photo)
    mainloop()
```

the mainloop() from tkinter GUI, which might not influence the logic in this code

Comment: Does this help? [Failed to parse netParameter file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55792523/13552470)

Comment: Still unresolved. 'failed to parse file' seems not to be a specific error.  Just executing the first line reports the error, is it some environmental problem?